# flush out buffer into file

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  string line;
  char buff[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
  {
     cin.get(buff[i]);
     cout.put(buff[i]);
     if(i==10)
     {
       ofstream file;
       file.open("TEXT",ios::out);
       for (i=0 ; i<10 ;i++)
         file << buff[i] << endl;
       file.close();
     }
  }
}
```

this code is not flushing the data from array to file and even file is also not created...

Comment: Stop if(i==10) never pass! becouse i<10 put i<= 10

Comment: I'm not sure how this compiles. You are missing a return value from the definition of `main`, there are no `#include` that define `string`, `cin` or `cout` and no `std::` or `using std::string`, etc. Please make sure that your posted code samples are complete.

Comment: You're also trying to use the same loop variable `i` for two nested loops.

Comment: Someone should post a corrected version, one that follows C++ standard practice...

Comment: I fixed your indentation for you. It was tedious, but the code did really hurt the eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because inside your loop, `i<10`, so your conditional is never executed. Put the flushing code *after* the loop.